# Pandas GroupingBy and finding repetition by unique IDs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    userId  date    new doa
67  23  2018-07-02  1   2
68  23  2018-07-03  1   3
69  23  2018-07-04  1   4
70  23  2018-07-06  1   6
71  23  2018-07-07  1   7
72  23  2018-07-10  1   10
73  23  2018-07-11  1   11
74  23  2018-07-13  1   13
75  23  2018-07-15  1   15
76  23  2018-07-16  1   16
77  23  2018-07-17  1   17
......
194605  448053  2018-08-11  1   11
194606  448054  2018-08-11  1   11
194607  448065  2018-08-11  1   11
```

`df['doa']` stands for day of appearance.

Now I want to find out like which unique `userId`s have appeared on a daily basis. Like which `userId`s are appearing on day1, day2, day3, and so on. So how do I exactly `groupby` them? And also I want to find out like the avg. no of days unique users are opening the app in a month?

And finally I want to also find out like which users have appeared at least once every day throughout the month.

I want some thing like this:

```
userId  week_no ndays 
 23        1     2     
 23        2     5
 23        3     6
.....
 1533      1     0
 1534      2     1
 1534      3     4
 1534      4     1
 1553      1     1
 1553      2     0
 1553      3     0
 1553      4     0
```

And so on. `ndays` means no. of days in a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking several different questions, and none of them are particularly difficult, they just require a couple groupbys and aggregation operations.

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'userId': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3],
    'date': ['2018-07-02', '2018-07-03', '2018-08-04', '2018-08-05', '2018-08-06',
    '2018-07-02', '2018-07-03', '2018-08-04', '2018-08-05', '2018-07-02', '2018-07-03',
    '2018-07-04', '2018-07-05', '2018-08-06']
})

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df['doa'] = df.date.dt.day

    userId       date  doa
0        1 2018-07-02    2
1        1 2018-07-03    3
2        1 2018-08-04    4
3        1 2018-08-05    5
4        1 2018-08-06    6
5        2 2018-07-02    2
6        2 2018-07-03    3
7        2 2018-08-04    4
8        2 2018-08-05    5
9        3 2018-07-02    2
10       3 2018-07-03    3
11       3 2018-07-04    4
12       3 2018-07-05    5
13       3 2018-08-06    6
```

***Questions***

1. How do I find the unique visitors per day?

You may use `groupby` and `unique`:

```
df.groupby([df.date.dt.month, 'doa']).userId.unique()

date  doa
7     2      [1, 2, 3]
      3      [1, 2, 3]
      4            [3]
      5            [3]
8     4         [1, 2]
      5         [1, 2]
      6         [1, 3]
Name: userId, dtype: object
```

2. How do I find the average number of days per month users open the app?

Using `groupby` and `size`:

```
df.groupby(['userId', df.date.dt.month]).size()

userId  date
1       7       2
        8       3
2       7       2
        8       2
3       7       4
        8       1
dtype: int64
```

This will give you the number of times per month each unique visitor has visited.  If you want the average of this, simply apply `mean`:

```
df.groupby(['userId', df.date.dt.month]).size().groupby('date').mean()

date
7    2.666667
8    2.000000
dtype: float64
```

3. This one was a bit more unclear, but it seems that you want the number of days a user was seen per week:

You can `groupby` `userId`, as well as a variation on your `date` column to create continuous weeks, starting at the minimum date, then use `size`:

```
(df.groupby(
    ['userId', (df.date.dt.week.sub(df.date.dt.week.min())+1).rename('week_no')])
    .size().reset_index(name='ndays')
)

   userId  week_no  ndays
0       1        1      2
1       1        5      2
2       1        6      1
3       2        1      2
4       2        5      2
5       3        1      4
6       3        6      1
```

Comment: How  do I calculate no. of unique `userId`s coming as a list of values in the first answer? Like I want to append  a new column with the length of the list.
Also I want to make a dataframe whereby I want to show the `userId`s and a column with frequency, sorted in ascending order. If you can please attach it with the answer

Comment: Like if `userId 1` comes every two days in a week then frequency is 2/7=0.29 avg.